# Cannot to connect to my website in local network IIS (SSL) with another PC

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, iis, ip, https

I'm working to a project ASP.NET core, I have created an SSL certificate for HTTPS and it's working, but only on my PC.
I have created a "fake" DNS so if on my PC I write `my.site.com:7001` it's working.
Then, I have tried it on another PC and it doesn't work, I have tried to disable the firewall and change hosts file in Windows and to change some settings in IIS. Now I don't know how to resolve this. Can someone help me?

[image: HOSTS FILE]

I know that in this file I have written many random things, but the first line is right.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Can you please update your question by adding your hosts fileof the 1st PC and the one from the 2nd PC?

Comment: thanks, ok now i update my question, but the file on second pc is set like deafult, beacuase my site will be read by many PCs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second PC needs to know that `my.site.com` can found on the first PC; you can achieve this either using DNS or by editing the `hosts` file on the second PC.

Without this, the second PC has no way of knowing where to look for `my.site.com`.

Comment: i dont think that i can write in italian, but is there a way to do all on my pc (Server)? i can't do this on every pc in the company

Comment: Then you need to use DNS. This is exactly its purpose. If you don't manage DNS in your company, ask your administrator to create a DNS record for your site.